# Cannot run ruby IRB on Manjaro 18.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb, manjaro

Running ruby scripts from the command line works as it should, but attempting to start the IRB results in a long list of gem dependency errors and a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/bin/irb:9:in `<main>'
        4: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        3: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        2: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:1397:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system (LoadError)
        14: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/bin/irb:9:in `<main>'
        13: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        12: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        11: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:1397:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
         9: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:161:in `rescue in require'
         8: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:204:in `try_activate'
         7: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:996:in `find_by_path'
         6: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:815:in `stubs'
         5: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:932:in `dirs'
         4: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:420:in `path'
         3: from /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:374:in `paths'
         2: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
         1: from /var/lib/snapd/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gem::PathSupport (NameError)
```

Ruby was already installed on the system and I also installed the ruby snap package, but cannot get it to work. The system and all packages are fully updated. Seeking help from anyone who has encountered a similar problem.

Comment: Not sure if it's going to solve this specific issue, but I suggest you to look into a ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm

Comment: What do you get for `which irb`?

Comment: Also have you tried `pry`? You can `gem install pry`, it's a much better irb.

Comment: @Beartech the output is `/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/irb`

Comment: OK, looking at the other end of the stack trace I see `uninitialized constant Gem::PathSupport (NameError)` so it's a path error. Have you tried closing and reopening the terminal session to pick up any path changes? Also try `bundle exec irb`.

Comment: @Beartech I took @Viktor 's advice and installed rvm which solved the problem, irb works perfectly now! BTW, tried `pry`, and it is much better than `irb`.